# MySQL INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY with PK and Unique

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Assume the following table (let's call it abc) structure, with a being the Primary Key and b being a UNIQUE column

```
a | b | c
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9
10 | 11 | 12
```

Assume the following MySQL statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO abc (a, b, c) VALUES (7, 5, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = 7, b = 5;
```

the ON DUPLICATE part of the statement is executed because it's finding 2 duplicate entries (row 2 and row 3).  The problem is, even the ON DUPLICATE part fails because if it chooses to update row 2 with the values provided, it will duplicate the Unique key of row 3, and vice versa. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why would you update a PK?

Comment: @Strawberry It's not an auto_increment PK.

Comment: Further, this is obviously a simplified example, in our example we actually have a multiple column PK.

Comment: Can we see that then? And it's *obviously* not obvious! ;-)

Comment: Most importantly you didn't specify the desired outcome. What exactly would you like it to do when you run into this situation?